# is it necessary that all data of one form should go into one table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2005

is it necessary that all data of one form should go into one table?
(i am developing an website for franchise management of an educational institute in which i have given inquiry form which is quit big.)

Comment: you need to give much more details to get useful answers... what is the base problem you are trying to solve ? what is the exact goal ? will it be necessary to search over complete data ? if performance is a factor: have you done realistic performance tests ?

Comment: this is franchise management system for educational institute on which i am working. it has many forms like inquiry, registration,follow up, course prize list etc. i am using .net  with c# and sql server 2005 database

Comment: how to attach many tables to one form? if it is not necessary that data from one form should go to one table??

Answer (score 0):

you can have any number of table in a single form and you can send specific data. This means that it is not necessary to send all the table's value through form post/get method.

I recommend you to visit this link which talk detail about the form-based programming:
[Form-based Programming in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164151.aspx)